# 3rd-party tool for analysis converts its report to the Generic Issues format in sonarcloud

Tags: openedge, sonarcloud, angularjs-3rd-party

We are using the progress (Open Edge) programming language and running the CI in azure pipelines we are planning to run a scan in sonar cloud, but sonar cloud does not support by the progress language.

1. To run code analysis need 3rd part tool, can you please mention those tools
2. How to use in sonar cloud/azure pipeline please explain
3. how to convert report to the Generic Issues format in sonar cloud.

I asked CABL (Code Analyzer for ABL) tool but its not supported by the sonarcloud

Please suggest.

Comment: There are SonarCode support at the [SonarCloud Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/sc/9). I think they can best answer your question there.

Comment: And asking here for tool suggestions is off topic. Also, you're asking how to do something with azure pipeline but you're also saying sonar cloud does not support that? I'm quite lost here...